# Color cast in scanned color negatives

Tags: film, color, scanning

I've been struggling with color cast in film scans for way too long now -almost a year. It's high time I ask for help.

The shot below was taken on a Kodak Gold 200, I metered the exposure with a Sekonic Studio Deluxe III; the metering I don't specifically recall, but it was consistent with Sunny 16, I might have even overexposed it by one stop.

I developed the roll with Tetenal C41 chemicals on 38 degrees Celsius, with the prescribed timings found in the datasheet. The development shouldn't be an issue, since the same color cast I came across whilst scanning rolls developed by a professional lab.

I scanned the film negative with PrimeFilm XAs using Silverfast software. Below is the result:

[image]

I have come to the conclusion that this is a scanning issue, yet, no matter how much I play with Silverfast settings, I haven't managed to put the issue at ease.

Anyone having faced the same issue, kindly guide me.

Regards,

Elvis

Comment: This is unfortunate. My guess is it is development. But have you scanned color negatives developed by a commercial lab? If so did they exhibit the same color cast? Was the film expired? How was it stored? Have you had the negative scanned by a professional service?

Comment: Hey Bob! The color negatives developed by a commercial lab did exhibit the same color cast when I scanned the negatived on my own. The film wasn't expired; no clue regarding the storing conditions -I shot immediately after I got the film. I guess I will have to have negatives also professionally scanned; I pressume however they would resort to some post-processing which I'd like to be able to do on my own.

Comment: This is more than just a colour cast - there's something very wrong here. First thing I would try is reset all the scanner software settings. If you can't manage to do that easily, a quick way would be to connect the scanner to a computer it's never been connected to before, and install SilverFast there from scratch. If nothing improves, take this frame to a photo lab and have them print just that frame - it might actually be cheaper than their scanning price. See how the print turns out. You should have real-world colours - this looks like what you might see on an old broken TV or something.

Comment: Isn't the blue color cast just the inverted orange cast of the negative? Using plain color inversion is not the way to do it for a color negative.

Comment: @xenoid Silverfast has presets based on the film manufacturer for performing the inversion. In other words, I haven’t plainly inverted.

Comment: @osullic said, "more than just a colour cast..." That image has a [solarized look](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sabattier_effect) to me. Tones in the surface of the platform look inverted to my eye\* while tones in other parts of the image seem more normal. Could the film have been exposed to light during development? [\* Look especially at the square drain grate in the foreground, the drain holes are _white_.]